# Como corrigir esse erro de Undefined Variable?

Tags: php, html, html5, mysqli

Estou a semanas tentando resolver esse negócio de `php` porém já fiz de tudo e nada funciona. (É um sistema de controle de visitantes)
Segue abaixo os meus códigos.

form-visitantes(html em php).php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include_once ("./classes/visitante.classe.php.php");
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8" />
<title>Controle de Visitantes</title>
<style type="text/css">

<!--
.style1 {
color: #FF0000;
font-size: x-small;
}
.style3 {color: #0000FF; font-size: x-small; }
</style>
<!---->
</script>
</head>
 
<body>
  <form name="form-cadastrarVisitantes"  method="POST" >
  <form id="visitantes" name="visitantes" method="post" action="visitantes.php" >
  <table width="625" border="0">
  <tr>
  <td width="69">Nome:</td>
  <td width="546"> <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Insira o nome do cidadão" required="required" id="nome" size="70" maxlength="60" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>RG:</td>
  <td><input name="rg" type="number" placeholder="999.999.999-99" required="required" id="rg" size="11" maxlength="11"/>
  <span class="style1">*</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Sexo:</td>
  <td><input name="sexo" type="radio" value="Masculino" checked="checked" />
  Masculino
        <input name="sexo" type="radio" value="Feminino" />
        Feminino <span class="style1">*</span>  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Telefone:<td/>
        <input name="telefone" type="number" placeholder="(99)99999-9999" required="required" id="telefone" />
        <span class="style3">Apenas números</span> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Estado:</td>
  <td><select name="estado" required="required" id="estado">
        <option>Selecione...</option>
        <option value="DF">DF</option>
        <option value="MG">MG</option>
        <option value="PR">PR</option>
        <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
        <option value="RS">RS</option>
        <option value="SC">SC</option>
        <option value="SP">SP</option>
        </select>
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
  <td>Cidade:</td>
  <td><input name="cidade" type="text" placeholder="Insira a cidade do cidadão" required="required" id="cidade" maxlength="20" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Endereco:</td>
  <td><input name="endereco" type="text" placeholder="Insira a rua do cidadão" required="required" id="endereco" maxlength="20" />
        <span class="style1">*</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2"><p>
  
        <input name="cadastrar" type="submit" id="cadastrar"  value="Concluir o cadastro!" />
       
 
        <input name="limpar" type="reset" id="limpar" value="Limpar campos preenchidos!" />
  
  
         
 
        <span class="style1">Campos com * são obrigatórios!</span></p>
  <p>  </p></td>
  </tr>
 </form>
 </body>
   
 
  <?php
 
      if (isset($_POST["nome"]) ){
                        $id = 0;
      $nome = $_POST["nome"];
      $rg = $_POST["rg"];
      $telefone = $_POST["telefone"];
      $estado = $_POST["estado"];
      $cidade = $_POST["cidade"];
      $endereco = $_POST["endereco"];
      $sexo = $_POST["sexo"];
      $visitante = new Visitantes ($id, $nome, $rg, $telefone, $estado, $cidade, $endereco, $sexo);
      $visitante->cadastrarVisitante();
      
                    }
         
                  ?>
      

 
  </table>
</html>
```

visitantes.classe.php

```html
<?php

 class Visitantes {
  
  private $id;
  private $nome;
  private $rg;
  private $telefone;
  private $estado;
  private $cidade;
  private $endereco;
  private $sexo;
  
  function __construct($id, $nome, $rg, $telefone, $estado, $cidade, $endereco, $sexo) 
  {
   $this->id = $id;
   $this->nome = $nome;
   $this->rg = $rg;
   $this->telefone = $telefone;
   $this->estado = $estado;
   $this->cidade = $cidade;
   $this->endereco = $endereco;
   $this->sexo = $sexo;
   
  }

   function setId($id) {
   $this->id = $id;
  }
   function setNome($nome) {
   $this->nome = $nome;
  }
   function setRg($rg) {
   $this->rg = $rg;
  }  
   function setTelefone($telefone) {
   $this->telefone = $telefone;
  }    
   function setEstado($estado) {
   $this->estado = $estado;
  }
   function setCidade($cidade) {
   $this->cidade = $cidade;
  }  
   function setEndereco($endereco) {
   $this->endereco = $endereco;  
  }
   function setSexo($sexo) {
   $this->sexo = $sexo; 
  }
  
   function getId() {
   return $this->id;
  }
   function getNome() {
   return $this->nome;
  }
   function getRg() {
   return $this->rg;
  }
   function getTelefone() {
   return $this->telefone;
  }
   function getEstado() {
   return $this->estado;
  }
   function getCidade() {
   return $this->cidade;
  }
   function getEndereco() {
   return $this->endereco;
  }
   function getSexo() {
   return $this->sexo;
  }
  
  
  function cadastrarVisitante(){
   
 
 
       include ("conexao.php");  
   
   {
      
      $sql = "INSERT INTO visitantes (id, nome, rg, telefone, estado, cidade, endereco, sexo)
       VALUES ('$id', '$nome', '$rg', '$telefone', '$estado', '$cidade', '$endereco', '$sexo')";
       
       $query = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die (mysqli_error($link));
       echo "Erro ao adicionar a DB.";
       

      echo '<script type="text/javascript">
      alert("Salvo com Sucesso!");
      window.history.go(-1);
      </script>';
      echo "<script>location.href='listarVisitantes.php';</script>"; 
      
      mysqli_close($link);
       
   } 
  }
 
  }
  function buscarVisitante($visitanteBuscado){
 
   try {
     
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=80;dbname=visitantes', 'bernardo', 'qweqweqwe1');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT id, nome, MASK(rg, '### ### ### ##'), telefone, estado, cidade, endereco, sexo FROM visitante");
  
    if($visitanteBuscado != ""){
     $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT id, nome, rg, telefone, estado, cidade, endereco FROM visitante WHERE nome like '%".$visitanetBuscado."%'or cns like '%".$visitanteBuscado."%';");
    } 
    echo "<div class='panel panel-info'>";
    echo "<div class='panel-heading'>Visitante</div>";
    include_once ("C:/xampp/htdocs/recepcao/buscarVisitante.php");
    
    echo "<table class=table>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Nome</th>";
    echo "<th>RG</th>";
    echo "<th>Telefone</th>";
    echo "<th>Estado</th>";
    echo "<th>Cidade</th>";
    echo "<th>Endereco</th>";
    echo "<th>Sexo</th>";
    echo "<th>Editar</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>". $linha["nome"] ."</td>";
     echo "<td>". $linha["MASK(rg, '### ### ### ##')"] ."</td>";
     echo "<td>". $linha["telefone"] ."</td>";
     echo "<td>". $linha["estado"] ."</td>";
     echo "<td>". $linha["cidade"] ."</td>";
     echo "<td>". $linha["endereco"] ."</td>";
     echo "<td>". $linha["sexo"] ."</td>";
     echo "<td><a href='atualizarVisitante.php?id=$linha[id]'><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' aria-label='Left Align' >
       <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' aria-hidden='true'></span>
     </button></a></td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<div class='panel-footer panel-info'>
      <form name='form-index' method='POST'>
       <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' onClick='history.go(-1)' style='margin-left:10px;'>Voltar</button>
      </form>
     </div>";
    echo "</div>";
    
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Erro ao buscar';
    echo $e;
   }
  }
    
  function buscaVisitante () {
 
   try {
     
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=80;dbname=visitas', 'bernardo', 'qweqweqwe1');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       
    $consulta = $pdo->query("SELECT id, nome, rg, telefone, estado, cidade, endereco, sexo FROM visitante WHERE id =".$this->id.";");
   
    echo "<form name='form-atualizar-Visitante' method='POST' >";
    
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     echo "<div class='form-group'>";
     echo "<label for='nome'>Nome</label>";
     echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='nome' 0 aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='' name='nome' value='". $linha['nome'] ."'>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "<div class='form-group'>";
     echo "<label for='rg'>RG</label>";
     echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='rg' 0 aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='' name='rg' value='". $linha['rg'] ."'>";
     echo "<label for='telefone'>Telefone</label>";
     echo "<input type='date' class='form-control' id='telefone' 0 aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='' name='telefone' value='". $linha['telefone'] ."'>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "<div class='form-group'>";
     echo "<label for='estado'>Estado</label>";
     echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='estado' 0 aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='' name='estado' value='". $linha['estado'] ."'>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "<div class='form-group'>";
     echo "<label for='cidade'>Cidade</label>";
     echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='cidade' 0 aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='' name='cidade' value='". $linha['cidade'] ."'>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "<div class='form-group'>";
     echo "<label for='endereco'>Endereco</label>";
     echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='endereco' 0 aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='' name='endereco' value='". $linha['endereco'] ."'>";
     echo "</div>";
     echo "<div class='form-group'>";
     echo "<label for='sexo'>Sexo</label>";
     echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='sexo' 0 aria-describedby='emailHelp' placeholder='' name='sexo' value='". $linha['sexo'] ."'>";
     echo "</div>";
    }
    echo "<div class='panel-footer panel-info'>
      <form name='form-index' method='POST'>
       <button type='button' class='btn btn-info' onclick='atualizar()'>Salvar</button>
       <button type='button' class='btn btn-info' onClick='history.go(-1)' style='margin-left:10px;'>Voltar</button>
      </form>
        </div>";
    echo "</form>";
    
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
      function atualizar() {
       var nome = document.getElementById('nome');
       var rg = document.getElementById('rg');
       var telefone = document.getElementById('telefone');
       var estado = document.getElementById('estado');
       var cidade = document.getElementById('cidade');
       var endereco = document.getElementById('endereco');
       var sexo = document.getElementById('sexo');
       var end = '?id=$this->id&&nome='+nome.value+'&rg='+rg.value+'&telefone='+telefone.value+'&telefone='+telefone.value+'&estado='+estado.value+'&cidade='+cidade.value+'&endereco='+endereco.value+'&sexo='+sexo.value;
       window.location.replace('./atualizarVisitante.php'+end);
      }
     </script>";

   } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Não foi possível encontrar este visitante!';
   }
  }
    
   function atualizarVisitante() {
   if (isset ( $this->id )) {
     
    try {
     $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=80;dbname=visitas', 'bernardo', 'qweqweqwe1');
     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
     $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE visitante SET nome = :nome, rg = :rg, telefone = :telefone, estado = :estado, cidade = :cidade, endereco = :endereco, sexo = :sexo WHERE id = :id');
     $stmt->execute(array(
       ':id' => $this->id,
       ':nome' => $this->nome,
       ':rg' => $this->rg,
       ':telefone' => $this->telefone,
       ':estado' => $this->estado,
       ':cidade' => $this->cidade,
       ':endereco' => $this->endereco,
       ':sexo' => $this->sexo,
     ));
     
     echo $stmt->rowCount();
     echo "
     <script>
      var mensage = alert('Visitante atualizado com sucesso!');
      window.location.replace('./listarVisitantes.php');
     </script>";  
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
   }
  }
  
   function excluirVisitante($id) {
   if (isset( $id )) {
    
    try {   
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=80;dbname=visitas', 'bernardo', 'qweqweqwe1');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM visitante WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();  
    
    echo $stmt->rowCount();
    echo "
     <script>
      var mensage = alert('Visitante excluído com sucesso!');
      window.location.replace('./listarVisitantes.php');
     </script>";  
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
   }
   
  }
 ?>
```

conexao.php

```html
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'bernardo', 'qweqweqwe1', 'visitas');
if (!$link) {
    die('Erro ao conectar ao banco: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Conectado com sucesso! ';
?>
```

**Não reparem nas outras funções em PDO. Estou me concentrando apenas na function CadastrarVisitante.**

Erro:

```html
Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\recepcao\classes\visitante.classe.php.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined variable: nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\recepcao\classes\visitante.classe.php.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined variable: rg in C:\xampp\htdocs\recepcao\classes\visitante.classe.php.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined variable: telefone in C:\xampp\htdocs\recepcao\classes\visitante.classe.php.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined variable: estado in C:\xampp\htdocs\recepcao\classes\visitante.classe.php.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined variable: cidade in C:\xampp\htdocs\recepcao\classes\visitante.classe.php.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined variable: endereco in C:\xampp\htdocs\recepcao\classes\visitante.classe.php.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined variable: sexo in C:\xampp\htdocs\recepcao\classes\visitante.classe.php.php on line 87
Duplicate entry '' for key 'rg'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nenhuma das variáveis passadas no insert existe. Você deve passar os atributos da classe no lugar.

Mude:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO visitantes (id, nome, rg, telefone, estado, cidade, endereco, sexo)
VALUES ('$id', '$nome', '$rg', '$telefone', '$estado', '$cidade', '$endereco', '$sexo')";
```

Para:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO visitantes (id, nome, rg, telefone, estado, cidade, endereco, sexo)
VALUES ('$this->id', '$this->nome', '$this->rg', '$this->telefone', '$this->estado', '$this->cidade', '$this->endereco', '$this->sexo')";
```

Answer (score 2):

O meu, descobri que o erro era oriundo de um atrubuto com erro ao usar espressar no encapsulamento referente. tipo, era para ser `$this->valoredida;` eu coloquei `$this->$valormedida`, ou seja estava chamando uma variável inexistente, uma vez que para referenciar a variável da classe, você tem que colocar o `$this` antes e colocar o dolar só no `$this`, ficaraia assim então:

```
$this->valormedida;
```

e se for no set, ficaria:

```
$this->valormedida = $valormedida
```

Espero ter ajudado.